# How do I make player_1 move with keys?

Tags: python, pygame, pong

I want to make a Pong game in Python. I already have the windows and the player models.

I tried to make it with

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x -= speed
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x += speed
```

this is my whole code:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import math
import random
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # fps

pygame.init()  # start
title = pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
width = 640
height = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))   # screen
running = True
speed = 10
white = (255, 255, 255)
x = 120
y = 5
player_1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (240, 430, x, y))
player_2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (240, 40, x, y))
pong = pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (300, 235), 4)
pygame.display.update()
fps = clock.tick(60)
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x -= speed
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x += speed


while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
```

I wanted to make the lower player to move with the arrow keys but nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x -= speed
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x += speed

player_1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (240, 430, x, y))
player_2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (240, 40, x, y))
pong = pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (300, 235), 4)
pygame.display.update()
fps = clock.tick(60)
```

within the while loop.

Also, change

```py
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x += speed
```

to

```py
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    x += speed
```

Comment: ```while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= speed
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += speed
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
```
I changed it to that but it still does not move when I use the arrow keys.

Comment: Not inside the ```for``` loop but immediately afterwards. See my edit.

Comment: I changed it but not it only draws a line to the left for both players

Comment: Can you elaborate? I would recommend really looking into what your code is doing.